# Count RDL grouping

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, rdl

In RDL grouping for second time rendering we need show a row, do we have an option to count group rendering & based on that can we do visibility true or false.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do visibility based on almost anything.  I'm not sure if I've enough information in your question, but if you want to hide/show based on the row, you could use RowNumber(nothing)  to obtain the number of row you're in.  (VStudio - SSRS).

Comment: So you could do something like this: iif(RowNumber(nothing)>1,show,hide)